Categorical duals for Yetter-Drinfeld modules
Yetter-Drinfeld (YD) modules appear naturally in the theory of Hopf algebras. They are both modules and comodules at the same time, satisfying a certain compatibility condition, as presented here. The category of YD modules admits a natural tensor product giving it the structure of a monoidal category. Is this category rigid i.e. do fin-dim YD admit right/left duals in the monoidal category?
